# Best workout time vs eating time

Tags: running, cardio, calories

At the beginning of the year, i started my own weight loss plan (eat less, move more), and it was successful in that i lost just over 3 stone (44lbs). It slowed down a lot after 4 months and i more or less gave up trying, but mostly kept the weight off (put 4 lbs back on).

I have recently decided to finish what i started and shed the last stone and have taken up running, and would like to know, when am i better eating. I am trying to both increase my fitness, and burn off some fat. So would i be better eating a hour or so before running, or right after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running before eating will provide you with the best opportunity to burn more body fat. However, if your undernourished you will not be able to exercise well, which will defeat the purpose of going to the gym.

If your trying to build your physique I'd suggest eating before. If your trying to slim down, I'd suggest exercising first. 
However, this is very important. Make sure that after your work out you don't eat in excess because you're starving. Make sure to fill up on water with your meal. It'll slow you down from wanting to eat more than your body needs.

Comment: Im strictly controlling my calories, but on its own, that isnt doing the job any more, this is why i took up running, so over eating isnt an issue here, i have a set meal that would be ready when i get back, and i would give myself time to cool down before i ate also. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend eating at least 2 hours before your workout for showing better performance during your workout (if you re going to eat carbohydrate foods, you should consider eating 2 hrs before your workout for improving performance because body first uses these as energy source). And as Sean has also told, don't eat too much after your workout, it is generally being ignored which causes reducing benefit from your exercise. Drink one bottle of mineral water during the post workout meal.